# flask-sqlalchemy foreignkey populating table with null

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to implement a foreign key at one of my tables in flask-sqlalchemy, but keep getting this error all the time:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "user_id" of relation "applications" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, Company ABC, Software Engineer, New York, NY, USA, Applied, , 2022-09-09, null).
```

Here is the code:

```
from flask_login import UserMixin

from database.database import db


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     email = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
     password = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
     name = db.Column(db.String(), default='', nullable=True)
     application = db.relationship('JobApplicationTracker', lazy=True,backref='author')

    
     def __repr__(self) -> str:
         return self.email

     def __str__(self) -> str:
         return self.email
```

code:

```
from database.database import db

class JobApplicationTracker(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'applications'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    notes = db.Column(db.String(), default='', nullable=True)
    date_applied = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.title} at {self.name}'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} at {self.name}'
```

I have an "applications" table and a "users" table.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you have set nullable=False for user_id column in your JobApplicationTracker model but when trying to add, you are passing null value for user_id.

You can try creating a user, pass that user id and things should work fine.
If you want it to work without user id, trying having nullable=true. Again, changing it in the model won't get reflected in the table. You might have to manually change it in the database

Comment: It's still giving me the same error. I have created a user and passed the user id

Comment: Could you please paste the request and error?

Comment: `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "user_id" of relation "applications" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains (Google, Software Engineer, Chicago, IL, USA, 2, Applied, , 2022-09-16, null).
`

Comment: You may have added a user but in the SQL insertion, null value is passed (Google, Software Engineer, Chicago, IL, USA, 2, Applied, , 2022-09-16, **null**)